# Installing NORDVPN on Kali LInux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, vpn

I just purchased a vpn through NORD and I am following the steps they layout on their site but it is not working for me.

Steps:

1. Get the NordVPN repo setup .deb package
   You can Download the file here or at the top of this page
2. Install the NordVPN repository
   Open the terminal and run the following:
   sudo apt-get install {/path/to/}nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
3. Update the apt-get package list
   Type this command:
   sudo apt-get update
4. Install NordVPN
   Almost there! Enter the last command to install NordVPN:
   sudo apt-get install nordvpn

After I run the install nordvpn command I get this message"

`sudo apt-get install nordvpn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
nordvpn is already the newest version (3.2.0-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 632 not upgraded.`

So the next steps say to run

`5. Log in to your NordVPN account:

nordvpn login

6. Connect to a NordVPN server:

nordvpn connect`

So I run nordvpn login but get the following:

`nordvpn login
Whoops! Cannot reach System Daemon.`

I could not find the same issues on google/this site for someone trying to install NORDVPN on Kali Linux. Please help.

Comment: Also, you have 632 packages not upgraded. When was the last time you ran `sudo apt upgrade`? You need to do "upgrade" to apply software updates.

Comment: Follow mchid answer if it won't work remove NordVPN completely including the configuration files update your system and install NordVPN freshly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the NordVPN is already installed.

However, according to [this post on archlinux.org](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nordvpn-bin/?O=10&PP=10#pinned-671373), you need to enable and start the systemd service for NordVPN.

Please run the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl enable nordvpnd
sudo systemctl start nordvpnd
```

*Enabling the service* means that it will be automatically started on every future boot. The `start` command starts the service immediately. There are also `disable` and `stop` commands that do opposite thing.

If you want to see whether the service is running, stopped or failed, issue this command:

```
sudo systemctl status nordvpnd
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the *Whoops! Cannot reach System Daemon* error on Fedora 31 after each system restart. I'm resolving it by running:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
sudo systemctl restart nordvpnd.socket
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo nordvpn login` then `sudo nordvpn connect`  broh